# Homebrew throwing warning: "Calling depends_on :x11 is deprecated! Use depends_on specific X11 formula(e) instead"

Tags: homebrew, x11

Very new to all this and apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

Long  story short, I tried installing proxychains with homebrew and ran:

```
brew install proxychains-ng
```

to which I recieved the following:

> Warning: Calling depends_on :x11 is deprecated! Use depends_on specific X11 formula(e) instead. Please report this issue to the d12frosted/emacs-plus tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus/Formula/emacs-plus@27.rb:49

I don't know what this means or why this came up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, but I was able to solve it in my case by running "brew update" in the terminal and then re-running my "brew install" command.